# Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Ive been having this issue for a while now. The response is from my backend api and its saying this property dosent exist even though it exists. I have a total of like 18 errors in my angular application and it was working all fine until today and I dont know what to do to fix this "issue".

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenService } from '../../authentication/services/token.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AdminService } from '../../authentication/services/admin.service';
import { CrudService } from '../services/crud.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private _token: TokenService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _admin: AdminService,
    private _crud: CrudService
  ) {}

  adminId: string;
  adminName: string;
  adminEmail: string;
  users: any[];
  deletedId: string;
  successMessage: string;
  p: number = 1;
  loading: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = 'true';
    this._token.verifyToken().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.adminId = res.admin._id;
        localStorage.setItem('adminid', this.adminId);
        this._admin.getAdminById(this.adminId).subscribe((res) => {
          this.adminName = res.admin.name;
          this.adminEmail = res.admin.email;
          this._crud.readAllUsers().subscribe((res) => {
            this.users = res.users;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.loading = '';
            }, 950);
          });
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 400) {
            this._router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  deleteUserById(id: string) {
    this._crud.deleteUser(id).subscribe(() => {
      this._crud.readAllUsers().subscribe((res) => {
        this.users = res.users;
        this.successMessage = 'User succesfully deleted';
      });
    });
  }

  removePopup() {
    this.successMessage = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: try: (res) => {console.log(res)}, what logs ?

Comment: My api response and I cant even do that right now since my application wont work. The part that dosent make sense is even though I had nearly 20 errors everything in my application was working fine until yesterday

Comment: thats sad, do you have a backup? it's a good practice ...

Comment: does getAdminById() have a return type interface? is admin defined on that?

Comment: @sonEtLumiere I have a backup on my github

Comment: @proxima-b I never made a interface since everything was working fine and I dident see a need for it.

Comment: @lizardcoder Always add interfaces :) your future self with thank you. It should also fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is because you have made HTTP calls without returning a specific type hence TS infers type `Object`

Below should work. Change code in the ngOnInit to

```typescript
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = 'true';
    this._token.verifyToken().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.adminId = res.admin._id;
        localStorage.setItem('adminid', this.adminId);
        this._admin.getAdminById(this.adminId).subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.adminName = res.admin.name;
          this.adminEmail = res.admin.email;
          this._crud.readAllUsers().subscribe((res) => {
            this.users = res.users;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.loading = '';
            }, 950);
          });
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 400) {
            this._router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

note I have added `(res: any)`

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend using "any" anywhere. Always use a fully defined interface to help with readability, and to help protect yourself from future breaking changes

Comment: @proxima-b sometimes you may be called upon to solve the current problem in the fastest way possible. At such moments you may have to use some not very good approaches to solve the problem. In future they can be refactored  and improved upon

Comment: @proxima-b Thank you and now I understand and I will add interfaces to my code